# How to read an array "list" & print it in prolog?

Tags: prolog

How to read an array "list" & print it in prolog ?
I need to :- 
Prompt user to insert an array 
The user some how tells me that He's finished 
Then I print it

I just can't think of how to make this in a predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you would like to have?

```
1 ?- p(X).

|: a.

|: b.

|: c.

|: d.

|: end.
```

Code:-

```
X = [a, b, c, d].
```

This is how one can implement this behaviour:

```
p(X) :- read(A), q(A,X-[]).

q(end,X-X) :- !.

q(A,[A|X]-Y) :- read(B), q(B,X-Y).
```