# Prolog difference list - mergesort

Tags: prolog, difference-lists

I must write predicate which will split one list into two lists (on halve):

```
halve(X-Y, X-Z, Z-Y) :- halve_pom(X-Y, X-Y, Z), !.

halve_pom(Z-Y, Y-Y, Z).

halve_pom([_|A]-Y, [_,_|B]-Y, Z) :- halve_pom(A-Y, B-Y, Z).
```

That was easy, but now I must write algorithm which will do mergesort - I don't have any idea. This algorithm must use difference lists.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

No, it was not "easy", as it doesn't work, unfortunately. `halve([1,2,3]-[],A,B)` doesn't work; `halve_pom([1,2,3]-[],A,B)` doesn't work either. Also, it is unclear which of the splitting schemes you prefer, `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] -> ([1,3,5,7] , [2,4,6])` or `-> ([1,2,3,4] , [5,6,7])`.

If your `halve` predicate worked, all you'd have left to do is to define `merge`, which would merge the two halves of a list, *in order*. Then,

```
mergesort(A,S):- halve(A,B-[],C-[]), mergesort(B,SB), mergesort(C,SC),
  merge(SB,SC,S-[]).
```

Note that you probably would call it with a normal list `A`, i.e. the `halve` predicate should expect its first argument as a normal list (i.e. not a difference-list).

See also [What does the "-" symbol mean in Prolog when dealing with lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456014/what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-prolog-when-dealing-with-lists) . The `'-'` is unnecessary; instead, its two constituents should be used as two separate arguments to a predicate.

---

So, one way to code `halve` is

```
halve([A,B|C],[A|X]-ZX,[B|Y]-ZY):- halve(C,X-ZX,Y-ZY). 
halve([A],[A|X]-X,Y-Y). 
halve([],X-X,Y-Y).
```

The same approach can be used to code `merge`:

```
merge(SB,SC,S-Z):- SB=[A|B], SC=[C|D], A=<C, S=[A|T], merge(B,SC,T-Z).
merge(SB,SC,S-Z):- SB=[A|B], SC=[C|D], A>C,  ... ,    ... .
merge(SB,SC,S-Z):- SB=[A|B], SC=[],          ... ,    ... .
merge(SB,SC,S-Z):- SB=[], SC=[C|D],          S=[C|T], ... .
merge([],[],Z-Z).
```

Comment: For my edification could you show how to do `halve/3` with difference lists, using the odd/even splitting scheme? I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks. :) I "get" DLs in a vague, conceptual way, but apparently not well enough to actually use them.

Comment: @DanielLyons I think that's it. Good that you asked, turned out I had to fix it a bit. see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion_modulo_cons#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons

Comment: @DanielLyons Glad to help. Instead, let me just up-vote your comment; feels as good. :) This stuff is made unnecessarily hard by using too vague a language, in the books. Just call them "open-ended lists" and all  is simple and clear!

Comment: I have come up with a solution using flip/flopping accumulators instead of three cases: `halve([], X-X, Y-Y).  halve([A|C], [A|X]-ZX, Y-ZY) :- halve(C, Y-ZY, X-ZX).`. I'd like to have your feedback on it if you have a minute to take a look.

Comment: @DanielLyons ah, very nice, the rotating accumulators! :) It extends to three-way partitions too: `three([], X-X, Y-Y, Z-Z). three([A|B], [A|X]-ZX, Y-ZY, Z-ZZ) :- three(B, Y-ZY, Z-ZZ, X-ZX).` I first saw something like that in [a post by ed'ka in F# tag](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7945580/849891).  Translates to Haskell too. `threeWay xs = foldr (\x (b,c,a)->(x:a,b,c)) ([],[],[]) xs`. In Prolog it is much simpler. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27037/discussion-between-will-ness-and-daniel-lyons)